# If $\omega + 1 = \omega$, find $\omega$ ($\omega \not= - \infty$ or $\infty$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, infinity

> If $\omega + 1 = \omega$, find $\omega$ ($\omega \not= - \infty$ or $\infty$).
>      It does not have to be a real number.

My teacher gave us this question just to play around with, and my first guess was **there was no value** because for any value of $\omega$

$$
\omega + 1 = \omega \\
\omega - \omega + 1 = 0 \\
1 = 0
$$

and $1 \not= 0$ (I think).

Then I tried to assume that $\omega = \infty$, but unfortunately I can't use that.

So then I tried another way..

$$
\omega +1 = \omega \\
\omega -\omega + 1 =0 \\
\omega(1-1) = -1 \\
\frac{\omega(1-1)}{-1} = 1 \\
-(1-1) = \frac{1}{\omega} \\
\therefore 0 = \frac{1}{\omega} \text{ where 1 has to equal 0..}
$$
 But this is so wrong, $1$ does not equal $0$. So can anyone find a value (if one exists) for $\omega$ that would satisfy the equation above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $\omega$ is a real number, then there is no value of $\omega$ that can satisfy the equation.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche It does not have to be real, I'll add that into my question, sorry!

Comment: @SamirChahine If every element has an additive inverse, then there is no number satisfying your equation.

Comment: Every infinite cardinal satisfies this equation.

Comment: @tetori Could you please prove this? Thank you

Comment: suppose that $1=0$. Perhaps $\omega$ is a member of a trivial monoid. (i.e. $\omega=1=0=1\cdot\omega=\omega+0$)

Comment: The letter $\omega$ really shouldn't be used here.

Comment: @GitGud Was a fancy question, would it be wise to change it to $z$?

Comment: @SamirChahine It wouldn't harm, but I'm not sure it's necessary. The title of the question caught my attention because it looked like you might have been talking about the least infinite [ordinal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) which is denoted by $\omega$. By the way, if it had been $1+\omega=\omega$, then  it would be true with this meaning of $\omega$ I gave.

Comment: @SamirChahine I think he want you to understand effect of unnecessarily removing powers, I mean changing $$(\omega +1)^n = \omega^n$$ to $$\omega+1=\omega$$

Comment: I see what he's trying to say but I did not change the powers, which is why the question is near impossible for me to do, otherwise I would have said the same thing @DigitalBrain

Comment: @SamirChahine I write answer about it, but I have doubts about readability of my answer.

Comment: If you change your domain to a modular ring, it works. For instance, if your domain is reals mod 1 (fractional parts, wrap around), then for instance $\omega=1/2$ yields $\omega+1=\omega =1/2 \mod 1$ and the same for any $\omega$ you want. Of course $1=0 \mod 1$ so this is not a problem.

Comment: @SamirChahine What exactly was your teacher trying to say then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the question must be  find $\omega$ if 
$$(\omega+1)^n=\omega^n$$
Because he mentioned that $\omega$ don't have to be real
$$(\omega+1)^n=\omega^n$$
$$\omega^n(1+\frac{1}{\omega})^n=\omega^n$$Since $\omega\neq 0$ 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{\omega}\right)^n=1$$
$$(z)^n=1$$
$$z=1^{1/n}$$
$$z=\left[\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)\right]^{1/n}$$
$$z=\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)$$
$$z=e^{2ki\pi/n}$$
since $z=1+\frac{1}{\omega}$
$$\omega=\frac{1}{z-1}$$

$$\omega=\frac{1}{e^{2ki\pi/n}-1}$$

Comment: This should be a comment… But good point.

Comment: There were no powers in his question, but if powers were to be added in order to solve for $\omega$, could you please show how? Thank you @digital-brain

Comment: @SamirChahine This way

Comment: @petajamaja Now I don't think, I should have commented this

Comment: I cannot take it from there, although I will keep trying and use what you have given me as a start, I am yet to find the answer though.. I also find it hard to solve given the fact that this question was given to my class with no powers, he would have hinted it if we required them, so there must be another solution. @DigitalBrain

Comment: @SamirChahine Is it okay Now?

Comment: Why did you raise it to the $n$-th? It should be solved for $n=1$, otherwise it seems to me that you are adding solutions to the equation that will not satisfy the initial one. If you solve for $n=1$ however your solution for any $k$ gives $\omega = \frac{1}{0}$, which is not what was asked for. What am I missing here? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @patatahooligan I'm not raising powers, I'm saying that we can solve for some **non-real** $\omega$ If the question is find $\omega$ if $$(1+\omega)^n=\omega^n$$, And I'm talking about nth complex roots of unity. And obvoiusly there are no complex roots for n=1.

Comment: @DigitalBrain Ah, I misread it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Now the answer looks as an answer =) In the previous form it was a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If it was $1+\omega=\omega$, then the [ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) $\omega$ could be the answer.
Are you sure you did not reverse the sum ?

Comment: This is similar to @GitGud's earlier comment on the question.

Comment: yes sorry didn't see it before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your teacher is thinking of $\omega=-\infty$.

Comment: A couple people in my class suggested that, but he said it still wasn't the answer he was looking for, pretty stupid question if you ask me..

Answer (score 1):

I do not certain that this 'answer' presents the answer which your teacher wants, since 'infinite cardinals' are some type of infinity.

In the case of finite sets, we can count the number of elements of the set and we can compare the 'size' of two sets. For example,
$A=\{25,39,93,1341,9999\}$
and $B=\{h,m,n,r,x\}$ have same number of elements, and in fact, they have 5 elements.

We can suggest the question naturally - we can compare the size of finite sets, but how to compare the size of *infinite* sets? We cannot 'count' the number of elements of infinite sets. However, if $A$ and $B$ have same 'size', we can correspond the elements of $A$ to the elements of $B$. For example, in previous example we can correspond the elements of $A$ to $B$ as follows:
$$25\mapsto n,\, 39\mapsto h,\, 93\mapsto m,\, 1341\mapsto r\text{ and } 9999\mapsto x$$

It is same for the case of infinite sets - that is, if there is a 1-1 correspondence between $A$ and $B$, we can consider that they have *same size*.
Mathematicians (exactly, set theorists) define a variety of kinds of infinite *sizes*. For example, we can think the *size* of the set of natural numbers. We call it *aleph-zero* and denotes $\aleph_0$, and it is the least *infinite cardinal*.

In the case of finite numbers, we can think the sum of *sizes*. For example, we can think $4+4$ and we know that it is equal to 8. Like the finite numbers, we can also think and define the sum of infinite cardinals. How to define it? At first, we consider the finite case. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, (that is every element of $A$ is not an element of $B$) then $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$. We can define the *addition of infinite sizes* similarly. Even if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint, we can make it disjoint. (For example, we can consider the set $\{(a,0):a\in A\}$ and $\{(b,1):b\in B\}$ instead of $A$ and $B$.)
From above discussion, we can define $\aleph_0+1$ and especially, we can get $\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$.